# Assigning hex value of short to short

Tags: c++, c, hex, short

```
 short c = 34;
```

and the hex value of c is 22.  How can I assign the hex value to a short variable (say short d) by converting 'c'?

like

```
   short d = 22;
```

Comment: Why doesn't d = 0x22; work"

Comment: How to do that by converting 'c' variable?

Comment: What about `short c = 10;` which in hexadecimal is `0x0A` - how do you plan to convert that?

Comment: But the hex value is also 10. I met into this situation to assign short value of hex to short. I'm doing for c > 16.

Comment: @John Victor hex value of decimal `10` is `0xA` as written above.

Comment: doing for c > 16 works fine.

Comment: @JohnVictor now try dec `26` (hex `0x1A`) =)

Comment: Bottom line is: "You can't store in integer those funny ABCDEF parts of hex, only 0123456789". If you have a programmer's calculator, play around with it (Windows 7/8 calculator will do the trick).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use a string buffer and [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) hex format.

Then write it back with [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  short c = 34;
  short d;
  char string[10];
  sprintf(string, "%x", c);
  d = atoi(string);
  printf("c = %d\n", c);
  printf("d = %d\n", d);
  return 0;
}
```

gives output

```
c = 34
d = 22
```

Comment: -1. [Try c = 10](http://ideone.com/d39ltg).

Answer (score 3):

`short` objects and other integer objects do not have decimal values or hexadecimal values. Their values are pure numbers.

Eleven, 11, and 0xb are different names for the same number.

To assign `d` the same value as `c`, use `d = c;`.

When you print with `printf`, you can have values formatted as decimal numerals or hexadecimal numerals. You can print the value of `c` as a hexadecimal numeral with `printf("%x", c);`.

Comment: Oh. But, is there any possibility to assign the value 22 to short? without printing. Just assigning.

Comment: @JohnVictor No. Because you never need this. In case of `c = 10` which value you will want to assign to `d`?

Comment: @JohnVictor: You must use the correct terminology to describe what you want. To put the **number** 22 into `d`, simply use `d = 22;`. If `c` has the value for the decimal numeral 34, and you want to put the value for the hexadecimal numeral 22 into `d`, simply use `d = c;`. That works because decimal 34 and hexadecimal 22 **are the same thing**. If you want to convert the value in `c` to a hexadecimal numeral and then reinterpret that text as a decimal numeral, you can do that with `sprintf` and `scanf`. That will not work if the hexadecimal numeral contains any digits from A to F.

Comment: @JohnVictor: Note the terminology:  A **number** is an abstract mathematical thing. A **numeral** is a **text string** that represents a number. `short` objects do not hold text strings; they only hold numbers.

Comment: I understood. :) Thank you for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any type of conversion when assigning from one short to another. To the PC, it's just a collection of bits. How you interpret them (as hex, decimal, etc.), is a high-level decision you code around. If you have the correct hex (or otherwise) value in "c", just assign it to "d."

Answer (score 1):

Machine knows nothing about numeral systems. They are for **human perception** of numbers.

You must only "translate" numbers when human-machine interaction happens:

- from human form to machine form on input (human >> machine)
- from machine form to human form on output (machine >> human)

Example of output:

```
short c = 10; // for you its "decimal ten" now, 
              // for machine is just a handful of bits
printf("d = %d\n", c);   // you explicitly say here to output as decimal
printf("d = 0x%.4X", c); // you explicitly say here to output as hexadecimal
```

So instead of trying to translate inside of logic part of program, go down to output part and translate there.

Hope it helps!